# PHP - What is the "data type" of $link in this case? $link = mysql_connect()

Tags: php, sqldatatypes, mysql-connect

**Disclaimer**

While I know the mysql_[command] functions are depreciated, this is for a school project and I started before they became depreciated. I don't get marked on the "up-to-date-ness" of the functions used, only the complex-nature of the program I have written therefore there was no incentive to change to PDO or mysqli. I have to include a variable-listing of all the variables I have used (including data type...) even though they aren't defined in the same way as vb.net for example.

**The big question I have!**

What is the data type of the variable `$link` in the code listed below? Where a data type is for example a string, integer, boolean value, etc...

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: It should be a resource if connected successful.

Comment: Doesn't the documentation answer this?

Comment: Is a resource a data type? Or is it PHP-specific?
The documentation doesn't answer this that I can see.

Comment: It's a PHP specific data type: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php All data types are language specific, it's just that most languages share many similar types and ideas about those types.

Comment: Just to make this clear: This is not the Google Search Input Field. This is Stack Overflow ;-)

Comment: Deceze actually answered my question - it was my misunderstanding of the documentation that a resource is a data type. I assumed that because I haven't heard of it  in this context that I was looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @Justice Also consider switiching to mysqli_connect since, as you've read in the documentation, mysql_* is deprecated. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it connects successfully it'll be a resource identifier, otherwise a boolean:

> Returns a MySQL link identifier on success or FALSE on failure.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php